# Deploying app part to office 365, takes long time to load

Tags: sharepoint-addin, deployment, office-365

When I am debugging the solution, the app part is working properly.
After testing I deployed this app part to Office 365 site, and added app part to the page. It's taking very long time to load the app part. What could be the issue?

Comment: What is the question? Please add more details about the app, what it is trying to show, technologies used etc.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I have implemented an app part that shows contents from tasks lists in a site. I have used Ajax calls to get the data. It works fine when I tried to debug it. but when I deploy it on office 365 it takes too much time to load app part. also after loading sometimes jquery function (button click) are not working.

Comment: I think we gonna need to see some code

Comment: I think if there is bug in the code then it should throw exception during debugging. Its working appropriate during debugging, Any guesses or comments that will primarily help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Well, the fact that it sometimes does not work at all (the on click) tells me that there must be a timing issue or a missing resource or something, therefore code is good..